Extracting unique values from a dynamic range, but repeating each value x times before next unique value
I have been trying to extract unique values from a range and repeat them, for which I've found this existing guide which seems to work:
Extracting unique values from a range, but repeating each value x times before next unique value
However, I am having issues changing this formula to be dynamic as my data range length changes each week.
I have tried to set the range as dynamic by editing the formula as below, but had no joy:
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/((COUNTIF($B$1:B2,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))<5)*(A:A<>"")),1)),"")

This has my Excel knowledge exhausted so any ideas would be hugely appreciated!
Thanks

In 365 this  formula can be used:
In cell C1 the number of repeat.
DROP are for cut the empty cell results from the functions.
The data range therefore should be continuous without gaps in the data.
The formula return string. If only numbers are used and number format is required wrap the last row in a VALUE function.
=LET(uni,DROP(UNIQUE(A:A),-1),
quant,C1,
DROP(VSTACK(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,REPT(uni&" ",quant)),," ")),-1))


